# How to Master Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My task is to tweak Google Analytics to fit complex needs for statistics of our website.

Google Analytics looks quite straightforward but on the other hand it seems to have lots of advanced features and endless possibilities and I don't want to learn by trial and error. I want to approach this task professionally.

What book, website or other resource would you recommend for studying purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongts [Clifton's book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720971/how-to-master-google-analytics/1720986#1720986), I recommend you to take the Google Analytics Individual Qualification test for which there is a lot of related [lessons in the Conversion University](http://www.google.com/support/conversionuniversity/?hl=en), and get subscribed to the [official Analytics blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/) to keep yourself up-to-date with the new features.

Answer (score 3):

I read the [Brian Clifton book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470253126) last summer, and it was pretty decent for a high level overview. Check out the [associated blog](http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/) too. Check out the Brian Clifton book

Comment: The book looks nice. However. Is it fresh enough? I mean one year is quite a lot in this industry. It might be obsolete already.

Comment: @Josef: most of the topics covered in the book are essential and conceptional keys to understand Analytics in deep. The source codes, however, need to be reviewed before usage since some API changes in the past.